# Rounding order volumes to a limiting total

Tags: sql, sql-server

Came across an interesting little problem at work yesterday. This is a question about arithmetic as much as SQL. Let's say you have a bunch of orders, and there is a limit to the volume that the orders can have (all 20 in this case):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#OMAX') is not null drop table #OMAX
create table #OMAX
    (
    OrderId int primary key,
    MaxVol decimal(15,3)
    )
insert into #OMAX(OrderId, MaxVol) values (1, 20), (2, 20), (3, 20)
```

And here are your order line items with their current, proposed, volumes:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#OLI') is not null drop table #OLI
create table #OLI
    (
    OrderId int,
    ProposedVolume decimal(15,3)
    )

insert into #OLI(OrderId, ProposedVolume)
values
    (1, 11.6),
    (1, 5.4),
    (2, 9.744),
    (2, 16.254),
    (2, 9.556),
    (3, 7.1),
    (3, 7.23),
    (3, 7.45)
```

You also want to round the results to a particular degree of accuracy, let's say that is 1.0 (whole numbers) for the moment:

```
declare @nOrderRoundAmt decimal(15,3) = 1.0;
```

**Question**: For orders whose current total is greater than the OMAX.MaxVol, can you write a SQL statement that will scale the ProposedVolumes down so that the new total of the order lines is equal to MaxVol? It has to be equal, not less than (reason: the business case here is that order 2 has a total proposed volume of 35.554, but we are saying that the max allowed is 20, so when we reduce the order we need to reduce it to 20, not any less as that would be unreasonable).

Complications: An order can have 1..N line items. Do not consider this an exhaustive set of test data, I suspect there are other tricky cases.

In this case order 1 should be untouched except for rounding, orders 2 and 3 should be reduced and rounded to 20.

Here is my best effort so far:

```
; with OrderTotals as
    (
    select OrderId, sum(ProposedVolume) as TotalVolume
    from #OLI
    group by OrderId
    )
select
    OLI.*, 
    Ratio.Ratio,
    Scaled.Vol as SVol,
    ScaledAndRounded.Vol as SRVol
from
    #OLI OLI
    join OrderTotals OT on OLI.OrderId = OT.OrderId
    join #OMAX OMAX on OLI.OrderId = OMAX.OrderId
    cross apply
        (
        -- Don't reduce orders that are already below the max.
        select
            case when OMAX.MaxVol / OT.TotalVolume > 1 then 1
            else OMAX.MaxVol / OT.TotalVolume
            end as Ratio
        ) Ratio
    cross apply (select OLI.ProposedVolume * Ratio.Ratio as Vol) Scaled
    -- Rounds to nearest.
    cross apply (select round(Scaled.Vol / @nOrderRoundAmt, 0) * @nOrderRoundAmt as Vol) ScaledAndRounded
    -- Rounds down.
    -- cast(Scaled.Vol / @nOrderRoundAmt as bigint) * @nOrderRoundAmt as ScaledAndRoundedDown,
```

This demonstrates two problems: order 2 comes out with a total of 19, and order 3 with a total of 21. You can stop order 3 from being more than 20 by always rounding down, but you can then get cases where the order total comes out at 18.

So is it possible in a single statement? My best solution so far is to apply the above logic (using round down) then apply a second step of processing in a cursor to add on differences until we get back to the total of 20.

Can you prove your solution works for all cases?

The following code for generating random orders for testing may be useful:

```
declare @OrderId int = 0, @NumLineItems int;

while @OrderId < 1000 begin
    set @NumLineItems = cast(rand() * 5 as int) + 1

    insert into #OLI(OrderId, ProposedVolume)
    select top (@NumLineItems) @OrderId, rand(cast(newId() as varbinary)) * 15
    from sys.objects

    set @OrderId = @OrderId + 1
end
```

**SOLUTION**

In case anyone is interested in the final solution I made based on Gordon's answer, here it is. It is a little verbose, returning far more columns than is actually required, but that aids debugging/understanding. Try setting the degree of rounding to 0.1 or 0.01. The solution is vulnerable to division-by-zero errors if any of the line items have a proposed volume of 0, but they are easily filtered out beforehand. It can also generate some line items that are rounded to zero, which need excluding after the fact.

```
declare @nOrderRoundAmt decimal(15,3) = 0.1;  -- Degree of rounding required.
if object_id('tempdb..#Results') is not null drop table #Results

select
    T.*,
    row_number() over (partition by OrderId order by Remainder desc) as seqnum,
    case
        when NeedsAdjustment = 0 then ProposedVolumeRounded
        else
            (case when row_number() over (partition by OrderId order by Remainder desc) <= LeftOver
            then AppliedVolInt + 1
            else AppliedVolInt
            end)
    end * @nOrderRoundAmt as NewVolume
--into #Results
from
    (
    select
        T.*,
        floor(T.AppliedVol) as AppliedVolInt,
        (T.AppliedVol - 1.000 * floor(T.AppliedVol)) as Remainder,
        T.MaxVol * 1.0 - sum(floor(T.AppliedVol)) over (partition by T.OrderId) as LeftOver
    from
        (
        select
            OLI.OrderId,
            OMAX.MaxVol as OrigMaxVol,
            MaxVol.Vol as MaxVol,
            OLI.ProposedVolume as OrigProposedVolume,
            ProposedVolume.Vol as ProposedVolume,
            ProposedVolumeRounded.Vol as ProposedVolumeRounded,
            sum(ProposedVolume.Vol) over (partition by OLI.OrderId) as SumProposedVolume,
            sum(ProposedVolumeRounded.Vol) over (partition by OLI.OrderId) as SumProposedVolumeRounded, -- Round, THEN sum.
            case
                -- when SumProposedVolumeRounded > MaxVol, i.e. the sum of the rounded line items would be
                -- greater than the order limit, then scale, else take the original.
                when sum(ProposedVolumeRounded.Vol) over (partition by OLI.OrderId) > MaxVol.Vol then 1
                else 0
            end as NeedsAdjustment,
            case
                -- when SumProposedVolumeRounded > MaxVol, i.e. the sum of the rounded line items would be
                -- greater than the order limit, then scale, else take the original.
                when sum(ProposedVolumeRounded.Vol) over (partition by OLI.OrderId) > MaxVol.Vol then MaxVol.Vol * (ProposedVolume.Vol / sum(ProposedVolume.Vol) over (partition by OLI.OrderId))
                else ProposedVolume.Vol
            end as AppliedVol
        from
            ##OLI OLI
            join ##OMax OMAX on OLI.OrderId = OMAX.OrderId
            cross apply (select OLI.ProposedVolume / @nOrderRoundAmt as Vol) ProposedVolume
            cross apply (select OMAX.MaxVol / @nOrderRoundAmt as Vol) MaxVol
            cross apply (select round(ProposedVolume.Vol, 0) as Vol) ProposedVolumeRounded
        ) T
    ) T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partitioning problem, where you are trying to have the results be integers (or equivalently, some fixed multiple of integers).  The strategy is to calculate everything as integers, find the remainder, and then apportion the remainder among the items.

Here is an overview of the calculation:

1. Calculate the new volume as a floating point number for each entry in the order
2. Separate the integer portion from the fraction in this volume.
3. Calculate the max volume minus the sum of the integer proportions.  The diffence is the amount you have to make up.
4. Enumerate the fractions, from the largest to the smallest.
5. Calculate the final amount as the integer amount plus either 1 or 0.  Use 1 when the enumeration is less than or equal to the amount to make up.  0 for the others.

The following SQL does this:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by orderid order by remainder desc) as seqnum,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by orderid order by remainder desc) <= LeftOver
             then AppliedVolInt + 1
             else AppliedVolInt
        end) as NewVolume
from (select t.*, floor(AppliedVol) as AppliedVolInt,
             (AppliedVol - 1.000*floor(AppliedVol)) as Remainder,
             maxvol*1.0 - sum(floor(AppliedVol)) over (partition by orderid) as LeftOver
      from (select oli.orderid, oli.ProposedVolume, omax.MaxVol,
                   sum(proposedVolume) over (partition by oli.orderid) as sumProposed,
                   omax.maxvol * (oli.ProposedVolume / sum(proposedVolume) over (partition by oli.orderid)) as AppliedVol
            from #OLI oli join
                 #OMax omax
                 on oli.orderid = omax.orderid
           ) t
     ) t
```

If you don't have integers the arithmetic is slightly more complicated (because of the use of the enumeration from (4) to (5).  My recommendation is to just multiply all numbers by a constant and turn it into the integer problem or multiply the enumeration in (4) by the factor.

And, yes, I have tested this on your test data.  It not only works logically but in practice.

Comment: Gordon, Very neat solution. It has one small flaw, in that it scales orders that are already below the the maximum, that was fairly easy to fix though (we must not scale orders where the sum of the rounded line items is less than or equal to the max). The variable rounding was also easy to deal with. I'll post my final code as an edit as there doesn't seem to be sufficient space in this comment box.

Comment: @PhilipDaniels . . . I am curious about a couple of things.  Why do you want the rounded totals to be integers, when the original values are decimal?  Also, you have some strange boundary cases.  For instance, if you have the values 19.8, 0.1, 0.1, and 0.1, then these will round to 20, 0, 0, 0.  Is this a possibility?  Is it desirable to have these values become 0?

Comment: Gordon, In my code the rounded totals do not necessarily come out as integers. If you set the @nOrderRoundAmount variable to 0.1, then everything will be rounded to 1 decimal place. I have tested this (using the code snippet in my question to generate a million random orders), it works OK. Secondly, yes it is ok for those to round down to 0. If my order had such line items they would be for very slow selling items, so they could go in the next order instead. In real life, this would be a vanishingly small possibility with no real noticeable affect.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

One possible approach is to

1. Get the 'most-rounded' proposed volume (in my example, the minimal difference between rounded and not rounded scaled volume);
2. If the total calculated volume is not equal to 20 and the ratio is not 1, correct that volume by 1.

*UPDATE:* As this just an example, there are some issues with the implementation

1. <del>`RR` and `RRS` should be joined the rank of proposed volume partitioned by `orderId` and sorted by `SDiffMax`. Joining by `SDiff` is *not* suitable for production;</del> FIXED
2. <del>It should make sure no volume is `0` after the correction (the best to do it is probably to exclude orders with `SRVol = 1` and `SDif < 0` from the calculation);</del> FIXED
3. <del>It's best to use a *relative* difference instead of *arithmetic* one, as in calculating the ratio of `SDiff` to `SVol` and using that value instead of `SDiff` further on would make the results significantly more accurate.</del> FIXED

Please let me know if you need any help with these.

**Solution**

```
; with OrderTotals as
    (
    select OrderId, sum(ProposedVolume) as TotalVolume
    from #OLI
    group by OrderId
    ),
 RawRounded as
 (
    select
        OLI.*, 
        Ratio.Ratio,
        Scaled.Vol as SVol,
        ScaledAndRounded.Vol as SRVol,
        (Scaled.Vol - ScaledAndRounded.Vol) / Scaled.Vol as SDiff,
        row_number() over (partition by OLI.OrderId order by (Scaled.Vol - ScaledAndRounded.Vol) / Scaled.Vol desc) as SDiffRank,
        TotalVolume
    from
        #OLI OLI
        join OrderTotals OT on OLI.OrderId = OT.OrderId
        join #OMAX OMAX on OLI.OrderId = OMAX.OrderId
        cross apply
            (
            -- Don't reduce orders that are already below the max.
            select
                case when OMAX.MaxVol / OT.TotalVolume > 1 then 1
                else OMAX.MaxVol / OT.TotalVolume
                end as Ratio
            ) Ratio
        cross apply (select OLI.ProposedVolume * Ratio.Ratio as Vol) Scaled
        -- Rounds to nearest.
        cross apply (select round(Scaled.Vol / @nOrderRoundAmt, 0) * @nOrderRoundAmt as Vol) ScaledAndRounded
),
RawRoundedSum AS
(
    select 
        OrderId,
        MIN(SDiff) AS SDiffMin,
        MIN(SDiffRank) AS SDiffRankMin,
        SUM(SRVol) AS SRVolSum
    from RawRounded
    where 
        Ratio <> 1
    group by OrderId
    having SUM(SRVol) <> 20
)
select 
    RR.OrderId,
    RR.ProposedVolume,
    case 
        when RRS.SDiffMin is null then RR.SRVol 
        else round(RRS.SDiffMin / @nOrderRoundAmt + case when RRS.SDiffMin < 0 then - 0.5 else 0.5 end, 0) * @nOrderRoundAmt + RR.SRVol
    end SRVolFinal
from 
    RawRounded RR
    left join RawRoundedSum RRS 
        on RR.OrderId = RRS.OrderId and RR.SDiffRank = RRS.SDiffRankMin
```

**Results**

```
OrderId     ProposedVolume                          SRVolFinal
----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           11.600                                  12.000000
1           5.400                                   5.000000
2           9.744                                   5.000000
2           16.254                                  10.000000
2           9.556                                   5.000000
3           7.100                                   6.000000
3           7.230                                   7.000000
3           7.450                                   7.000000
```

Comment: Serge, I made a small program to generate random orders and it pumped out a counterexample with just 2 line items: 13.581 and 11.568 (among many others). Your code rounds this to a total order volume of 19.

Comment: @PhilipDaniels Thanks for finding that out. It was a rather obvious mistake in `RRS` conditions. I fixed it and just in case I fixed the three concerns I had as well. One question is if it's acceptable to round to 0 the items with volume like .115. One could argue either way and it might be more of a business logic question.

Comment: this will still generate some wrong answers unfortunately. Try 6.258, 14.173, 9.925, 7.587, should come out as 18.